# Comparing Strings (C++)

Tags: c++, ifstream, istream

I am trying to get the amount of occurrences in a file of each word in a separate file. The following code should produce the number of occurrences of each word in **sl** using the words in **fl** but instead, it outputs **0** for each words even when there are many instances. I'm trying to figure out what the problem is and could do with some help. The **getNextWord()** function simply returns the next word in the file.

```
while(fl.isWord()){
        int total = 0;
        string temp1= fl.getNextWord();
        while(sl.isWord()){
            string temp2 = sl.getNextWord();
            if(temp1.compare(temp2)!=0) total ++;
          //if(temp1 == temp2) total++;

        }
        cout << temp1 << " " << total << endl;
}
```

The function isWords() is in a separate class:

```
bool ReadWords::isWord(){
    if(file.good())
        return !eoffound;
    else
        return eoffound;
```

Exemplar lists:

**fl content** kfc cows

**sl content:** damn cows cows chicken apples apples kfc food fat cows

**output:**

kfc 0

cows 0

**output should be:**

kfc 1

cows 3

*edited part:*

```
string ReadWords::getNextWord(){
    file >> theWord;
    return theWord;
}
```

Comment: whats the problem with `if(temp1 == temp2) total++;`

Comment: @BhawinParkeria I just commented it out because it produces the same result. compare() or == will produce the same result but the problem i guess is elsewhere :p

Comment: why dont you use .find() member function of the string ? Its easier and it will produce the result you want. For each word in the string, iterate through the other using .find() method. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Comment: can you post **getNextWord** function?

Comment: @KostasRim There are many other functions or implementations that I could apply and will work, logically, but I'm sure the error is to do with the loops here (i'm just guessing), else the output should be correct regardless of the efficiency of the function. I'm stuck with why it isn't showing the expected output :p

Comment: @AbdulRehman sure. i'll do that in a min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your functions for parsing the files are correct, there is a problem in the logic of the implementation. The problem is that after you get the first word from fl, you search the whole file sl, this one reaches its eof, then later searches will not work because sl is at eof.

What you need is a way to `seek` sl to its beginning after you finish with each word from fl.

```
while(fl.isWord()){
    /* seek sl to beginning; then do the rest */
    int total = 0;
    string temp1= fl.getNextWord();
    while(sl.isWord()){
        string temp2 = sl.getNextWord();
        if(temp1 == temp2) total++;
    }
    cout << temp1 << " " << total << endl;
}
```

EDIT: if you cannot find a way to seek the file, load all of its words into memory using `vector<string>`, in one pass, then do the search on this vector for each word from fl.

This will correct the *logic* of your implementation. HOWEVER, this is NOT to say that it is the recommended and "best" implementation (to avoid purists shouting at me :P ).

Comment: That's what I've been thinking for the past, who knows who long, but since the ifstream file is a private member of another class, i'm having trouble trying to access it within the loops. I think i sound confused as i can't clearly describe the issue but have an image of it in my mind. I hope someone understands what i mean :p

Comment: @NewToCoding You need to find a way to seek the file. If not, your implementation will never work.

Comment: @NewToCoding unless you first load the words from sl into an array, in one pass. See my EDIT.

Comment: Just played around with the code and now it seeks the file for every new word search. :)

Comment: @NewToCoding that is great :)